# Java: Is there a way to call a method while the original method terminates?

Tags: java, methods, swt, terminate

Here's my issue: I need the calling method terminate (otherwise my UI won't update itself), while the called method is still working. Atm it's something like this:

```
    public InGameGUI() {
        ...
        switchToRoboControl();
    }
```

and switch ToRoboControl is supposed to execute a solution on the UI. I thought about using a custom Listener-thingee but 1. I have no idea how to do that properly and 2. I was wondering if there are better ways. Threads are also not really the way to go since there are several methods that I need to call this way...

Comment: Look at you other question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronizing "Frontend" and "Backend" in Java (and SWT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24840762/synchronizing-frontend-and-backend-in-java-and-swt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `Threads`, this is precisely the use-case where they should be used.

> Threads are also not really the way to go since there are several
>   methods that I need to call this way...

And what stops you from starting and managing more `Threads` and possibly grouping some tasks together?

Also, if you are allergic to many Threads you can define a heartbeat event (a single separate thread, which is periodically active (like started one instance each second)) which would always check and run the tasks to be running and you could schedule the tasks in your main thread.

Comment: Using threads despite my allergy to threads helped, thank you! It was a pain, but now it works. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can take a looks at [AOP framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html) provided by Spring. There are various calls that you can make like executing some advice before or after a join point.

You only want a method or procedure to be executed at the termination of your method. Spring AOP provides much more than that. You can run methods before execution, after method return, after method throws exception or at all the three points.

You can write your own class that `implements AfterReturningAdvice` and override the `afterReturning()` method. In your spring configuration file create a proxy bean for your Class which has the `public InGameGUI()` method. In this bean you need to provide reference to the actual class object and your bean that references class implementing the `AfterReturningAdvice` as the interceptor name.

Comment: This is not a real answer, more a comment.

Comment: OP has asked for a way to call a method at some method termination which is precisely what I have mentioned. I don't see how this qualifies as a comment any more than the answer.

Comment: This points the user to a source of information, rather than helps him with his specific problem. At least give an example or some explination of how this will help him

Comment: What Vince said, and: OP has another question open where he asks for a answer to a very similar (I would say the same) problem.